# parallel stream is not working for multiple file upload to aws s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, java-8

The following method is written to parallel upload of files to AWS S3, but the parallel processing is not happening. It is taking 30 sec if uploading 30 files, the 50s if uploading 50 files.
I am not sure why the parallel() stream is not working in my use case. Any pointers will be appreciated

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> uploadMyFiles(MultipartFile[] files, String prefix) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    Stream.of(files).parallel().forEach(file -> {
        String fStatus =  uploadMyFile(file, prefix);                   
        map.put(file.getOriginalFilename(), fStatus);
    }); 

    return fileStatusMap;
}


public String uploadMyFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile, String prefix) {
    try {
        final File file = convertMPartFileToFile(multipartFile);
        uploadToMyBucket("mybucket", file, prefix);

    } catch (final AwsServiceException exception) {         
    
        return exception.getMessage()
    }
    return "OK";
}

private File convertMPartFileToFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    final File file = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    try (final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        outputStream.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("log error here");
    }
    return file;
}

private String uploadToMyBucket(final String bucket, final File file, String fileKey) {

    PutObjectResponse putObjectResult = s3Client
            .putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(fileKey).build(), RequestBody.fromFile(file));
    final URL myfileUrl = s3Client.utilities().getUrl(GetUrlRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(fileKey).build());

    return myfileUrl.toString();
}
```

Comment: please show the code inside uploadMyFile

Comment: A complete shot in the dark, but is the s3 handle capable of taking requests from multiple threads (e.g. would it just feed them through a single threaded worker)? It's been a while since I've worked with the api, consider the necessity of a thread-local handle for s3

Comment: added full code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `TransferManager` along with `ExecutorService` as shown in examples below;

[Parallelizing Large Uploads for Speed and Reliability](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/)

[Multipart Uploads in Amazon S3](https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-multipart-upload#6-controlling-upload-parallelism)

Comment: TransferManager  has a limit on the minimum threshold- 5MB per part except the last part. In my case, the files are less than 1 MB each. So technically I can't use it

Comment: @mark - MultipartUploadThreshold and MinimumUploadPartSize are configurable

Comment: ok. Do you think that will improve the performance? and also I have a requirement to return the status of each file upload(fail or success) at the end of upload any ideas on that?

Comment: I am trying it out but I just noticed that TransferManager is not supported in AWS SDK java2 version yet, My existing S3Client is using Java2 and I am unable to create TransferManager using the Java 2 s3 client!

Comment: yes, working on the same. any experience with the performance of uploading file size of less than 1MB. Once implemented it does not scale well, I have a rework! My file size can be between 3 KB to 2 MB size. So I am not sure if I can use the transfer manager, in this case, it splits the file into each 3 KB part in my case

Answer (score 0):

Steps for parallelising any piece of code in general (Have not worked with AWS, this is in general),

1. You need an `ThreadPool` to which you can submit a collection of `Callable<T>` for processing.
2. Piece of code to submit collection of `Callable` to the `ThreadPool`. Each Callable will be executed in the thread from the ThreadPool.
3. Piece of code to retrieve the result from collection of `Future<T>`.

This can be naively implemented through this example,

```
  public class S09 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    demoParallel();
  }

  public static void demoParallel() {
    ExecutorService eService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    String[] myArr = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
    Stream.of(myArr)
        .parallel()
        .map(S09::generateCallable)
        .map(eService::submit)
        .map(S09::obtainFuture)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static void demoMethod() {}

  private static Callable<String> generateCallable(final String input) {
    return () -> {
      System.out.println(
          "I am waiting here, " + Thread.currentThread() + " for Input String " + input);
      Thread.sleep(5000); // someExpensiveOperationHere
      return "Return Value of " + input;
    };
  }

  private static String obtainFuture(Future<String> futureString) {
    try {
      return futureString.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried already this code. I even  used AWS async client and submitted them with completeable future. It is improved little bit but not much.refer java example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html

Comment: another question on your reply, the parallel stream also achieve the same by running each task in a separate thread? do we really need to use callable in this case unless someone wants to manage the threads?